# How to access a method of an Activity inside TabActivity

Tags: android

I would like to access the public method of an Activity run by a TabActivity using:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
Intent intentMsgsView = new Intent().setClass(this, TeamHuddleScreenMsgsView.class);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("msgs").setIndicator("Messages").setContent(intentMsgsView));
```

Basically, what I what is to let the parent Activity call a method in child Activity in order to do something. Is this possible?

I did try this:

```
((TeamHuddleScreenMsgsView)getTabHost().getCurrentTabView().getContext()).refreshModel();
```

but I'm encountering a ClassCastException. It seems that the getContext() still gives the TabActivity. Any help on how to get the child Activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listen to what CommonsWare says here, I have gone this route and it was a horrible mistake, but here is how you do it.

```
((SportsActivity)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()).setLayout(R.layout.helpview);
```

Here `setLayout` is a public method I made in `SportsActivity`

Comment: awesome! it worked! and i agree, it seems that using Views instead of Activities would be better. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

This will be much simpler if you would not put activities in your tabs and just put views in your tabs, as that will mean there is only one activity. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab/) showing how this is done.

There is a `getActivity()` method on `ActivityGroup` (parent class of `TabActivity`) that is undocumented but might be what you want.